# sqlAlchemy converts geometry to byte using ST_AsBinary

Tags: sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I have a sqlAlchemy model that has one column of type geometry which is defined like this:

```
point_geom = Column(Geometry('POINT'), index=True)
```

I'm using geoalchemy2 module:

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
```

Then I make my queries using sqlAlchemy ORM, and everything works fine. For example:

data = session.query(myModel).filter_by(...)

My problem is that when I need to get the sql statement of the query object, I use the following code:

```
sql = data.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())
```

But the column of type geometry is converted to Byte[], so the resulting sql statement is this:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, ST_AsBinary(point_geom) AS point_geom 
FROM tablename WHERE ...
```

What should be done to avoid the conversion of the geometry type to byte type?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when was working with Flask-Sqlalchemy and Geoalchemy2 and solved this as follows.

You just need to create a new subclass of GEOMETRY type.

> If you look at [documentations](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html), the arguments of "GEOMETRY" type are given:

- **ElementType** - which is the type of returned element, by default it's *'WKBElement'* [(*Well-known-binary-element*)](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement)
- **as_binary** - the function to use, by default it's *'ST_AsEWKB'* which in makes a problem on your case
- **from_text** - the geometry constructor used to create, insert and update elements, by default it is *'ST_GeomFromEWKT'*

So what I did? I have just created new subclass with required function, element and constructor and used "Geometry" type on my db models as always do.

```
    from geoalchemy2 import Geometry as BaseGeometry
    from geoalchemy2.elements import WKTElement
    
    
    class Geometry(BaseGeometry):
        from_text = 'ST_GeomFromText'
        as_binary = 'ST_asText'
        ElementType = WKTElement
```

As you can see I have changed only these 3 arguments of a base class.
This will return you a String with required column variables.

Answer (score 0):

It think you can specify that in your query. Something like this:
from geoalchemy2.functions import ST_AsGeoJSON

```
query = session.query(ST_AsGeoJSON(YourModel.geom_column))
```

That should change your conversion. There are many conversion functions in the
[geoalchemy documentation.](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spatial_functions.html#geoalchemy2.functions.ST_AsBinary)